# Half precision CUDA

Tags: cuda, textures, gpgpu, precision

I am trying to use half precision for GPGPU computing. There is a confusion I need to clear

I could find references to all these things at the same time;

half floating data types supported as texture format, automatic conversion of half precision to float by texture hardware, *floattohalf* and *halftofloat* conversion functions supported on device only,and storing of half precsion values in *unsigned short* format.

So for all this to make sense, I have made these inferences.

CUDA supports two ways of handling half precicision.

1. Store float numbers in global memory. Convert them to half via *halftofloat*, store in unsigned short in global memory and reconvert to float via *halftofloat* before executing any operation.
2. (as texture memory is read-only from device) have numbers in half precision stored in unsigned short in host, store them in texture memory from host code, read via intrinsic TEX function and perform operations on it (without needing to convert to float).

Correct me if I am wrong?

Comment: Your summary is basically correct. You may be interested in this thread on the NVIDIA forums: https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/547080/-half-datatype-ieee-754-conformance/

Comment: Thank you both for your reply. I had already gone through both the posts but still wasn't sure if I got everything right. My bad.